# I want to do my home page responsive i am using using Divi builder

Tags: wordpress, divi

I have created a home page in WordPress using a Divi theme and Divi builder.
I want that page responsive (means I want when someone opens the site on mobile that person see one column but when someone open's it in the tablet that person see two-column). The issue is that the page is set on mobile with one column but when it comes to tablet it shows also has one column. But it has to see 2 columns. what to do now?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sir Thanks for the reply. I am using Divi theme and builder in WordPress on localhost then I came to know that Divi sometimes doesn't work properly on localhost.